# Ordering a string with numbers in ascending order

Tags: c#

I currently have a string that looks like this:

```
string numbers = "55;9;20;3";
```

How would i make the numbers in ascending order like this:

```
string numbers = "3;9;20;55";
```

Comment: Cool. What's the problem?

Comment: show how you tried to do it, what problems occurred, create some [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

You can try with a combination of String.Join, OrderBy and int.Parse like the following:

```
numbers=  String.Join(";", 
         numbers.Split(';').OrderBy(x=> int.Parse(x)));
```

You can check this [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kSd4p1) as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Linq` namespace for this:

```
using System.Linq;

 ...

  string numbers = "55;9;20;3";
  string output = String.Join(",", numbers.Split(';').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).OrderBy(x => x));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd break this into a four step process.

```
// 1) Split the numbers apart using based on the delimiting character ';' 
var splitString = numbers.Split(';');

// 2) Convert the array of `string` to an array of `int`
var numberArray = splitString.Select(x => int.Parse(x));

// 3) Order the array which has been output by the `Split` method.
var orderedArray = numberArray.OrderBy(x => x);

// 4) Join the string back together again in the correct order, delimited by ';'
var orderedNumbers = string.Join(";", orderedArray);
```

This could be squashed together into less lines of code, but by doing it in multiple stages it should give you a good understanding of what is happening.

For example, Here is the same logic in one line of code:

```
string orderedNumers = string.Join(";", numbers.Split(';').OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x)));
```